# Float left overridden in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-float

I have a simple webpage set up to test a method of centering a floated div. It is supposed to center the buttons and have them all float left. In chrome, the buttons are not floated. When I inspect element it shows that the float is overridden. I have checked the whole document, and there isn't any float: none, however chrome says there is. In internet explorer the website displays fine. Is this a problem with chrome's defaults? How do I fix it? From what I have learned CSS gives precedence to more specific orders, so the float: left in the li css should override any Chrome defaults...

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Center Floated Div</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
body {
    background-color: #32127A;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

#nav {
    float :right;
    position :relative;
    left :-50%;
    text-align :left;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style :none; 
    position :relative;
    left :50%;
}

#nav li {
    float: left
    position: relative; /* ie needs position:relative here*/
    }

#nav a {
    text-decoration :none;
    margin :10px;
    background :red;
    float:left;
    border :2px outset blue;
    color :#fff;
    padding :2px 5px;
    text-align :center;
    white-space :nowrap;
}

#nav a:hover{
    border: 2px inset blue;
    color: red;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    }

#content {
    overflow: hidden /* hide horizontal scrollbar*/
    }
```

Comment: you are missing `;` after the float...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `;` after the float in the css. You need to close it.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/re1a0bgz/)** (Working with the missing `;`)

Comment: I can't believe I missed that... I validated my html but not my css, I'll remember that next time!

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have a semicolon after the float. If the problem still persists you should add `!important` after the rule.